# jQuery animate() backgroundPosition not working fine

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, background-image, background-position

I have this simple HTML:

```
<span class="coverImg" style="background-image:url('images/show2.jpg');"></span></a>
```

and some Javascript:

```
$(function() {
            $(".coverImg").hover(function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    backgroundPosition : "0 0"
                }, "fast");
            }, function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    backgroundPosition : "50% 50%"
                }, "fast");
            });
        });
```

so when the mouseover the function is work correctly although the animation is not so perfect nice and easing is hardly seen..
but when mouseout the function is not working ,the background image just sit there not moving even on pixel...

What's the problem? What have I missed?

OR:

```
$(function() {
            $(".coverImg").mouseover(function() {
                $(this)
                .animate({
                    "background-position-x" : "-=20px",
                    "background-position-y" : "-=20px"
                }, "fast");
            }).mouseout(function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    "background-position-x" : "0 ",
                    "background-position-y" : "0"
                }, "fast");
            })
        })
```

this works only in the Chrome...

so again what's the problem ! what's the bug ! what i have miss?!

Comment: Please post your solution below and then "accept" your own answer.  That is the most proper way to answer your own questions here.

Comment: oh i see, forgive me for the first time, and actually i have been wrong about the my own solution....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think jQuery can animate background positions be default -- I use http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect

The standard CSS does not support the `background-position-x` and `background-position-y`, only a few support this like Chrome.

And jQuery's `animate()` method does not support animate two values at the same time, it'll turn out to be a error sometime or just do not doing anything in some browsers.

So after all, check this out http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations. There should be a jQuery plugin called `jQuery.bgpos.js` that works very well if you want to animate the background position.

Code is like this:

```
(function($) {
$.extend($.fx.step, {
    backgroundPosition : function(fx) {
        if(fx.state === 0 && typeof fx.end == 'string') {
            var start = $.curCSS(fx.elem, 'backgroundPosition');
            start = toArray(start);
            fx.start = [start[0], start[2]];
            var end = toArray(fx.end);
            fx.end = [end[0], end[2]];
            fx.unit = [end[1], end[3]];
        }
        var nowPosX = [];
        nowPosX[0] = ((fx.end[0] - fx.start[0]) * fx.pos) + fx.start[0] + fx.unit[0];
        nowPosX[1] = ((fx.end[1] - fx.start[1]) * fx.pos) + fx.start[1] + fx.unit[1];
        fx.elem.style.backgroundPosition = nowPosX[0] + ' ' + nowPosX[1];
        function toArray(strg) {
            strg = strg.replace(/left|top/g, '0px');
            strg = strg.replace(/right|bottom/g, '100%');
            strg = strg.replace(/([0-9\.]+)(\s|\)|$)/g, "$1px$2");
            var res = strg.match(/(-?[0-9\.]+)(px|\%|em|pt)\s(-?[0-9\.]+)(px|\%|em|pt)/);
            return [parseFloat(res[1], 10), res[2], parseFloat(res[3], 10), res[4]];
        }

    }
});})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thank you! i will checkout this . and i have found a another ways to fix the problem , check my EDIT! it works fine for me!

Comment: i just found this only works in Chrome , even not firefox... this has to be a bug....

Comment: demo:http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/ works in firefox...make sure this line: "background-position-x" : "0 " matches the example.

Comment: does the example site in my last comment work for you? (trying to narrow down bugs)

Comment: it works! what do you mean "make sure this line: "background-position-x" :'0 ' matches the example"?

Comment: i have been check a lot of questions,the background-position-x is not a standard css property, and animate() method can not animate two value correctly in every browser,so actually your first answer is correctly, check out this one [link](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations),the jquery plugin site has been down and you can found the plugin there ! really thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're using a heavy handed approach with jQuery. This can be done with css alone:

```
span {
    background: url(yourimage.jpg) top left no-repeat;
    transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
}

span:hover {
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

The background position change will be animated in modern browsers and will just be a static change in IE8 and under.

You may want to add the other browser specific prefixed versions of the `transition` property as well:

```
-webkit-transition:  
-moz-transition:  
-o-transition:  
transition:
```

Comment: Thank you ! -o-transition stands for Opera,right? i mean it should work fine in opera but it's not, it's wired....and IE9 does not support so well,either. chrome and FF work really good...i may have other bug?

Comment: i think -e-transition: is for IE9